# any information about en.quiente.info who has visited your account website

Tags: privacy, facebook

I ran across this site `http://en.quiente.info`, my friends tried it and they say it worked for them. It asks for most of the privileges on Facebook even sending messages on behalf of you.

Any one has an explanation for his. I didn't try it personally I'm afraid of losing my account.

Answer (score 1):

The site works (most likely- I haven't visited it either) by requesting YOUR permissions to see and record what YOU do. It then looks in its database to see if your friends also use it- if they do, it can show you what THEY have done.

It can't show you what anyone who is not a member of their site is doing, which is why it is so insistent that you get your pals to join.

It should unsurprising to anyone that using it is a terrible idea, and will turn predatory if not malicious at some point, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the site is supposed to analyze all your Facebook activity, including what you send, so it needs access to all those things. Their website doesn't really explain what they are trying to do, so I'm not sure what the risk/reward is.

Comment: They claim that they can show you who visits your profile, who reads your posts. is this technically possible?

Comment: If you give them full access to your account, then yes.

Comment: Is it really possible to get this kind of information, even if yo have full access to my account??

Comment: @iceDragon if you can't do it via the normal Facebook interface, I doubt it's possible at all (and even if it was, it doesn't justify the need for *write* access on the account), and this looks more like someone preparing a spam campaign (where the spammer sets up these fake sites, waits for enough users/idiots to grant access and forget to revoke it even though they realize the app doesn't work as promised, and finally uses all these accounts to post his spam at the same time - I've seen this on Twitter and it's pretty nasty and does quite a bit of damage)